# Is there a way to view all changes in my branch within a JetBrains IDE?

Tags: mercurial, jetbrains-ide, rider

I have a mercurial branch with three commits and I would like to view the aggregate changes of these three commits **within Rider**.

I have TortiseHg and BeyondCompare available to me, but I am wondering if I can achieve what I'm looking for within the IDE.

I know I can use the `Commit` and `Mercurial` tabs to view the changes for a single commit, is there similar way to view all of the file changes for a branch?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "all changes in a branch". A Mercurial branch contains some nonzero number of *commits*, with each commit representing a snapshot (the internal storage format is a curious mix of deltas and snapshots that you don't control). Each commit is on one specific branch and can be found only on that branch; `hg log -b <branch>` will show all the commits that are in that particular branch.

Comment: @torek Apologies I should have worded the question more precisely. I have updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this, here is how I'd do it:

You have a branch off `default` with three commits (`A`,`B`,`C`)

```
   C
  B
 A
D1
```

1. **Make sure you don't have uncommitted/working changes** - shelve or commit them if you do.
2. Update to the `default` branch which is the parent of your first branch commit (`D1`).
3. Without updating, revert all changes to commit `C` (say `C` is rev 1234).

`hg revert --all --rev=1234`

or if you using `thg` just right click on the `C` commit and click 'revert all files'
[image]

This updates your working directory to the changes made by commit `A`, `B`, and `C`,
allowing reviewing them as a single change.

This is often a useful thing to do before merging a feature branch back to `default`.

Answer (score 1):

For people using TortoiseHG (which is a common GUI front-end to Mercurial) it has a built-in feature for this.

In the Workbench window you can <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+click to select any two arbitrary commits in the history. Then right-click on one of those and select "Visual Diff".

That brings up a confirmation showing the relevant changed files. From there you can pick from one or more diff tools (I have WinMerge installed in addition to KDiff3 which comes with Tortoise) and click "Directory Diff".

(THG seems to know which available diff tools are capable of performing this action).

The diff tool should then show you first the difference between the sets of files, and then you can drill down into individual file diffs. (Both KDiff3 and WinMerge do this.)

Comment: Thanks for this. I should've specified in my question that I'm looking to try and do this within my JetBrains IDE without switching to another program like THG. I've updated it to reflect that now

Answer (score 1):

I found an approach using the Rider UI that ended up being slightly more inelegant version of [@Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/361714/tom)'s answer.

I start with 3 commits in a branch `new-branch` coming off `default`:

```
  @  dfa1d813a320 (new-branch) add file 3 [tip]
  o  38677ad21a87 (new-branch) add file 2
  o  f87856294900 (new-branch) add file 1
 /
o  3282081c6a8f (default)
```

I update to default with `hg up default`, go to the branch actions in the bottom right of Rider, find the name of my new branch in the branch list, select it and click `Compare`.

[image]

This brings up a popup view with commits on the left and file changes on the right. I select all of the commits and the file changes displays the changes for the whole branch.

[image]

I can then see aggregate branch changes for each file by clicking their names or cycle through all the changes by clicking the `Show Diff` button. This diff view is brought up back in the main Rider window. This is a little awkward but it does produce the required result.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is possible pretty easily:

1. Open the Git tab (Alt+9 keyboard shortcut in most cases)
2. Filter to just the specific branch you are interested it
3. Click on the newest commit in the branch (the top of the list)
4. Press Ctrl on your keyboard and keep it pressed
5. Scroll down in the list and click on the commit from which the branch was spawned off (it is easy to spot because the little circle glyph next to it will have a different color).

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mv1cF.png)

Comment: This doesn't work in my Mercurial case, it only shows the changes of the newest commit. 

It does work if I select all commits in the branch, however in a large codebase with many other devs & branches this can be pretty fiddly. I lean more towards the approach outlined in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72497057/13762264) because it collects all your branch commits for you.